# Installing Apache on a new Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 Instance and Stalled

Tags: 18.04, apache2, amazon-ec2

I recently logged into a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on my EC2 Instance. I ran the updates and upgrades and everything worked fine. I then restarted the server and went to install Apache.

I ran sudo apt-get install apache2. And everything was working fine until it go to here:

```
Enabling conf security.
Enabling conf serve-cgi-bin.
Enabling site 000-default.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service → /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache-htcacheclean.service → /lib/systemd/system/apache-htcacheclean.service.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.39) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
```

I left went to the store came back and it was still stuck there after an hour or so. I quit terminal logged back in and was able to start the Apache service. But is there a way to tell if the complete installation actually happened?

Comment: If apache is running without an issue then I guess it has been installed properly. If you wanna reinstall then you can try this command:
apt-get --reinstall install apache2 -y